# I "fixed" Apple's "QA:1702:How to capture video frames ... using AV Foundation." Why does an ivar work?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, video-capture, image-capture

Apple's "[QA:1702:How to capture video frames from the camera as images using AV Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1702/_index.html)" is "broken"without additional ivar code.

I found a fix - but what is an ivar and what is it doing in this case?

Here is the code that has to be added to Apple's TestAVViewController.h file:

```
@interface TestAVViewController : UIViewController <AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>

@property AVCaptureSession *session;  

@end
```

Here is the code that must be added to Apple's TestAVViewController.m file:

```
@implementation TestAVViewController
@synthesize session=ivarSession; // this creates an ivar
```

By adding both of those sections (which Apple does not provide), the following line will stop throwing a compilation error:

```
[self setSession:session];
```

What is the "session = ivarSession" doing that is preventing the compilation error?  Why does it make Apple's code work?

Answer (score 0):

The code you added creates and initializes a member variable.

Are you sure you copied the code correctly? The version I'm looking at on the page you linked to has `session` defined and initialized at the top of the `- (void)setupCaptureSession` message and that is the only message it is used in. This really should be a local variable, not a member variable.